# Copy a range of cells from one sheet and insert into next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy the data in a row(A1:B1) to the next empty row of another sheet and also delete the row. I have tried the following code but it is working only for a particular cell. Not sure how to do it for the next empty row. Can anybody help me?

Also I want this to happen whenever (A1:B1) is edited. The macro should initialize itself whenever A1:B1 is edited.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Range("A1:B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A32").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code module for the primary sheet (this is the one you wish to copy from), place this routine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column < 3 Then
            If Target.Row < 2 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                With Sheet2
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 2) = [a1:b1].Value
                    [a1:b1].Delete xlUp
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note: this efficiently does what you asked for, but seems like an odd request...

**UPDATE**

After looking at OP's workbook, this is the procedure that I furnished:

```
Sub Transfer2ndSheetRow1To1stSheet()
    With Sheet2
        If .[counta(1:1)] Then
            Sheet1.Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)(2).EntireRow = .[1:1].Value
            .[1:1].Delete xlUp
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Insurance. I always hate turning off events. If something goes wrong then the user's Excel is left in funky state. This way we ensure that when the procedure exits (and it will because of the On Error), events are turned back on.

Comment: Can you let me know how to do this? Should I replace this chunk of code instead of the previous one?

Comment: Just to be clear, the code should not raise an error, but you never know... ;)

Comment: Ah, your second comment clarified - it didn't look like it'd throw errors!  (sorry for tangent, but should I be using error handlers in macros? I don't think I've ever really looked in to them. What's best practice regarding error handling?)

Comment: Well, it depends...  It never hurts to do so, as long as you know what you are doing. For example, I would not recommend what I just did (On Error Resume Next) unless you really understand what's going on and how and when to turn error interruption back on.

Comment: The most common method is to use a GoTo statement to deal with the error condition in a common location (often at the bottom of a routine) no matter where it might occur in that routine.

Comment: And that, by the way, is one of the very few legitimate uses of `GoTo`.

Comment: Now with all that said, if your code is going to be used by other people besides yourself, then without question you need to handle errors as robustly as possible!

Comment: Doing it well requires a rather large chunk of knowledge. Here's a decent place to start (VBA is descended from Classic VB):  http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/debug.asp

Comment: @haimen Yes. Sorry I did not notice your comment. Yes. Use my code (and the instructions for it) instead of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ExcelHero!

Comment: @haimen I noticed your new question. Was there something faulty with this answer? If you need help, please ask.

Comment: @ExcelHero I was not able to do this one. The macro didnt work properly for me.

Comment: @ExcelHero I had a code which also did the part. So I thought I can modify that. Felt that was easy too. Can you help me on that?

Comment: You say it didn't work properly. What happened? Can you explain please?

Comment: @ExcelHero I am getting an error argument not optional

Comment: There is no line.. Once I run it, I am getting an dialog box in VBA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92908/discussion-between-haimen-and-excel-hero).

Comment: @ExcelHero you there?